# How to forward/redirect action from Struts Controller to Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, struct

I have 2 web application, one is in Struts and other in Spring running in Same server.

I wanna logout from Struts at the same time logout from Spring web app.

How can I forward/redirect from StructLogOut Action to SpringLogOut Action:

Will this work??

```
response.sendRedirect("/com/SpringAction");
```

Comment: It will work. Have you tried it?

Comment: Why it's not working? Are you getting 404? What location is your browser receiving in 302 response and what it should?